# "Unable to store the editor layout information." in Eiffel Studio

Tags: c++, c, eiffel

I have not really a programming issue but more like an IDE issue. My Eiffel Studio 15.01 won't start up because of this error shown on the picture in the link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCzrO.jpg

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Google brings up [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.eiffel.ise/8096) - any use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to go to menu View > Tools Layout > Reset Tools Layout

Otherwise remove the files under
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Eiffel Software\.es\15.01\docking
(or ~/.es/15.01/docking  in linux)

And restart EiffelStudio.